# ubuntu boots into emergency mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have w7 and mate 16.04  dualboot on my laptop. Suddenly linux stopped booting. I'm welcomed in the emergency mode and nothing helps to get through. In recovery the system is able to boot and work. I have tried already to perform  fsck on system drive and boot-repair... 
I will appreciate any help and advice

UPD
in the journal i an error saying that fcsk died with **status code 4** I have reinstalled system but the problem remains:-( The full list of errors is here:

```
failed to parse state file /var/ilb/systemd/rfkill/platform-thinkpad_acpi:bluetooth: Invalid argument
failed to parse state file /var/ilb/systemd/rfkill/platform-thinkpad_acpi:wwan: Invalid argument
failed to parse state file /var/ilb/systemd/rfkill/pci-0000:00:12.0-usb-0:4:1.0:bluetooth: Invalid argument
fsck failed with error code 4
Failed to start File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/479a30b2-def...
```

Comment: this is too broad to help you....you probably did something before and corrupted the system, more info is needed for this problem.

Comment: The emergency mode displays a command to show a journal - please do so and add the red error section to your post/question.

Comment: As i had a similar issues some days ago - my first workaround was selecting an older kernel version in the advanced options of Grub - consider trying that as well as a temporary fix.

Comment: selecting older kernel doesn't solve the problem. Only recovery boots.  In the journal I see that fsck throws an error "status code 4"